# Linear Independence

Tags: code-golf, math, linear-algebra

Given a set of vectors all of the same positive finite dimension, output a falsey value if they are linearly dependent and a truthy value if they are linearly independent. A set of vectors v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, ... is linearly dependent if for some scalars a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ... not all equal to 0,  a<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub> + ... = 0. (0 is the zero vector.)

Note: Using an inbuilt function to find the rank of a matrix or test vectors for linear dependence is not allowed.

Note 2: All input will be formed from integers.

Test cases (input -> output):

```
[[0,1],[2,3]] -> True
[[1,2],[2,4]] -> False
[[2,6,8],[3,9,12]] -> False
[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]] -> False
[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]] -> True
[[0]] -> False
[] -> True
[[1,1],[0,1],[1,0]] -> False
[[1,2,3],[1,3,5],[0,0,0]] -> False
```

Comment: Can we take the set of vectors as a rectangular matrix?

Comment: Yes, you can take the input as a rectangular matrix.

Comment: Can I take the number of rows and columns as additional input?

Comment: May we call a determinant built-in?

Comment: May we try to invert the matrix with a built-in and see if that succeeds? May we call a built-in to find all the eigenvalues?

Comment: @poi830 That seems really ad-hoc. To write a solution that uses linear-algebra functions, it seems like I'd have to guess what you'd allow or not. That strikes me as a mild case of [Do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/20260). I understand you don't want cheap solutions with built-ins that just do the problem, but it's a hard line to draw. In particular, many matrix norms and decompositions can indirectly tell you if a set of vectors are independent, even though that's not their purpose.

Comment: @xnor You could not have said it better

Comment: Edited, determinants and inversions of the matrix are now allowed, but may not be helpful because the matrix is not always square.

Answer (score 5):

## Matlab - <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```
@(A)det(A*A')>.5
```

If the product of the matrix and its transpose is singular, then the rows of the matrix are linearly dependent. The determinant is non-negative, and since the entries are integral (thank you Alex A.), the determinant is integral and can be compared to .5.

It would have been nice to just do `@(A)~det(A*A')`, but unfortunately `det` can give almost-zero for singular matrices.

[Try it on ideone](http://ideone.com/Dbh521)

Comment: _I didn't want to do arbitrary thresholding_ Using `eps` is actually arbitrary too :-) Maybe you want to use Ideone to provide an online demostration of your code for the test cases in the challenge (see for example my Octave answer). And welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @LuisMendo I meant the difference was in `det` vs `rcond`. `rcond` gives very small values for singular matrices compared to `det`. Will try to add ideone!

Comment: My point is: how can you be sure that you need to compare with `eps` and not with `10*eps` for example? Anyway, that probably happens to other answers too

Comment: @LuisMendo Of course you're right, with this kind of solution it's always possible to produce a large matrix that will break it. I have an exact solution also, do you think I should post it as another answer? By the way ideone doesn't seem to support Matlab

Comment: Posting several answers is welcome, as long as they are really different (different language, or different approach). In Ideone you can use [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), which is almost the same as Matlab. See [this](http://ideone.com/v3GsxB) for example

Comment: @AlexA. The claim is true. The rows of `M` being dependent with coefficients given by vector `v` means there that `v*M=0`. This implies that `v*M*(M^T)=0`, so `M*M^T` is singular, since it maps some nonzero vector to zero. Conversely, if `M*(M^T)` is singular, then there exists a vector `v` so that `v*M*(M^T)=0`, in which case `(v*M)*(v*M)^T=0`. But, only the zero vector has norm zero, so `v*M=0`, which means the rows of `M` have a linear dependence.

Comment: @xnor Very clear explanation!

Comment: @xnor That's great, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Since the input matrix is guaranteed to only contain integers, a nonzero determinant will be at least 1, so you can do `@(A)det(A*A')>.5` or similar.

Comment: @AlexA. Does Matlab have 0 Falsey and the rest Truthy? If so, you don't even need the `>.5`.

Comment: @xnor For instance one of the text cases gives  det(A*A')=1.7764e-15, which is truthy but should return false, that's why >.5 is needed

Comment: @AlexA.Great point, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
X->X==[]||eigmin(X'X)>eps()
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts a 2-dimensional array with the vectors as columns and returns a boolean. To call it, assign it to a variable.

For any real, [non-singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) matrix **X**, the square matrix **X**<sup>T</sup>**X** is [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix). Since a matrix is non-singular if and only if all of its column vectors are linearly independent and non-singular implies **X**<sup>T</sup>**X** is positive definite, we can declare the vectors to be linearly independent if the product is positive definite. A matrix is positive definite if and only if all of its [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) are strictly positive, or equivalently when its smallest eigenvalue is strictly positive.

So for an input matrix **X**, we construct **X**<sup>T</sup>**X** and get the minimum eigenvalue using `eigmin(X'X)`. To account for floating point error, we check this against the machine precision, `eps`, rather than 0, to declare positivity. Since we also want empty input to return `true`, we can simply add the condition `X==[]`.

Saved 1 byte thanks to Dennis!

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>72</s> 60 bytes

```r
function(x,m,n)!is.null(x)&&all(pracma::rref(x)==diag(,m,n))
```

This is a function that accepts the vectors as columns in a matrix as well as the dimensions of the matrix and returns a logical. To call it, assign it to a variable. It requires the `pracma` package to be installed but it doesn't have to be imported.

The actual checking for linear independence is done by row reducing the matrix to echelon form and checking whether that's equal to an identity matrix of matching dimension. We just need a special case for when the input is empty.

Saved 12 bytes with help from Luis Mendo!

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica - 29 bytes

```
#=={}||Det[#.Transpose@#]!=0&
```

Uses the property that the product of the eigenvalues of matrix A is equal to the determinant of A.

Sample

```
#=={}||Det[#.Transpose@#]!=0&@{{1,2,3},{1,3,5},{0,0,0}}
>>  False
```

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 14 bytes

```
M->det(M'M)>.5
```

Based on [@Anna's MATLAB answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78095) and [@AlexA.'s Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78128). Expects a matrix whose columns are the input vectors and returns a Boolean.

`det` returns a float, so we cannot compare the result directly with **0**. However, since the entries of **M** are integers, the lowest possible positive determinant is **1**.

#### Verification

```
julia> f = M->det(M'M)>.5
(anonymous function)

julia> [f(M) for M in(
         [0 2;1 3],
         [1 2;2 4],
         [2 3;6 9;8 12],
         [1 2 3;2 3 4],
         [1 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 1],
         zeros((1,1)),
         zeros((0,0)),
         [1 0 1;1 1 0],
         [1 1 0;2 3 0;3 5 0]
       )]
9-element Array{Any,1}:
  true
 false
 false
 false
  true
 false
  true
 false
 false
```

Answer (score 3):

## NARS2000 APL, 12 bytes

```
(≡≤-.×)⊢+.×⍉
```

#### How it works

```
(≡≤-.×)⊢+.×⍉  Monadic function. Right argument: M

           ⍉  Transpose M.
       ⊢      Yield M.
        +.×   Perform matrix multiplication.
              For empty M, this yields a zero vector (for some reason).
(     )       Apply this matrix to the matrix product:
   -.×          Compute the determinant.
                This (mistakenly) yields 0 if M is empty.
 ≡              Yield the depth of M (1 is non-empty, 0 if empty).
  ≤             Compare.
                Since 0≤0, this corrects the error.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, <s>32</s> 27 bytes

*Thanks to @Suever for removing 5 bytes!*

```
@(x)~numel(x)|any(rref(x)')
```

The code defines an anonymous function. To call it assign it to a variable or use `ans`. The result is a non-empty array, which in Octave is truthy if all its entries are nonzero.

[Try all test cases online](http://ideone.com/q8NrJg).

This is based on the [reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) of a matrix. A non-empty matrix is full-rank [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Computing_the_rank_of_a_matrix) each row of its reduced row echelon form contains at least one non-zero entry. This is checked by condition `any(rref(x)'`, where `'` can be used to transpose instead of `.'` because the entries are not complex. The empty matrix is dealt with separately by the condition `~numel(x)` (which is the same as `isempty(x)` but shorter).

Comment: Couldn't you remove the `all` based on this definition of truthy and falsey? http://ideone.com/Zd5gQa

Comment: @Suever Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 162

```js
M=>M.sort((a,b)=>P(a)-P(b),P=r=>r.findIndex(v=>v)).map(_=>M=M.map((r,i)=>(p=P(r))>q?(k=M[i],q=p,r):r.map((v,j)=>v*k[q]-k[j]*r[p]),q=-1))&&M.every(r=>r.some(v=>v))
```

Reduce the matrix and check if every row has at least 1 non zero element.

*Less golfed*

```js
M=>(
  P=r=> P=r=>r.findIndex(v=>v)), // First nonzero element position or -1
  // sort to have P in ascending order, but rows all 0 are at top
  M.sort((a,b)=>P(a)-P(b)), 
  M.map(_=> // repeat transformation for the number of rows
    M=M.map((r,i)=>(
      p = P(r),
      p > q
       ? (k=M[i], q=p, r)
         // row transform
         // note: a 0s row generate a NaN row as p is -1
       : r.map((v,j) => v*k[q] - k[j]*r[p])
     )
     ,q=-1
    )
  ),
  // return false if there are rows all 0 or all NaN
  M.every(r=>r.some(v=>v))
)
```

**Test**

```js
F=M=>M.sort((a,b)=>P(a)-P(b),P=r=>r.findIndex(v=>v))
.map(_=>M=M.map((r,i)=>
(p=P(r))>q?(k=M[i],q=p,r):r.map((v,j)=>v*k[q]-k[j]*r[p])
,q=-1))&&M.every(r=>r.some(v=>v))
  
console.log=(...x)=>O.textContent += x +'\n'

;[[[0,1],[2,3]] // True
,[[1,2],[2,4]] // False
,[[2,6,8],[3,9,12]] // False
,[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]] // False
,[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]] // True
,[[0]] // False
,[[0,0],[1,1]] // False
,[] // True
,[[1,1],[0,1],[1,0]] // False
,[[1,2,3],[1,3,5],[0,0,0]] // False
,[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] // True
].forEach(m=>console.log(m,F(m)))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
t!Y*2$0ZnYo
```

Thanks to Luis for golfing off two bytes.

Based on Anna's MATLAB answer.

## Explanation

```
t!Y*2$0ZnYo
t              duplicate input
 !             transpose
  Y*           matrix product, yields X^T * X
    2$0Zn      determinant
         Yo    round
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 with NumPy - <s>85</s> <s>112</s> <s>103</s> 102 bytes

```py
import numpy
x=input(i)
try:print reduce(lambda a,b:a*b,numpy.linalg.eigvals(x))
except:print(x==[])|0
```

Hopefully can get a few off, FGITW.

Comment: What is the significance of the `|0` in the final line?

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 33 bytes

```
|ssQt_w2$:GZy1)Z^!2$1!G*Xs!Xa~s3<
```

This uses [current release (16.1.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/16.1.0) of the language, which predates the challenge.

Input format is

```
[0 1; 2 3]
```

or

```
[[0 1];[2 3]]
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=fHNzUXRfdzIkOkdaeTEpWl4hMiQxIUcqWHMhWGF-czI8&input=WzAgMTsgMiAzXQ)

#### Explanation

This uses only integer opeations, so it is not subject to rounding errors (as long as the involved integers don't exceed `2^52`).

It works by applying the definition. It suffices to test for integer scalars *a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>, ... between −*S*−1 and *S*+1, where *S* is the sum of absolute values of all numbers in the input 2D array. In fact much lower values of *S* could be used, but this one requires few bytes to compute.

All "combinations" (Cartesian product) of values *a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>, ...  between −*S*−1 and *S*+1 are tested. The input vectors **v**<sub>1</sub>, **v**<sub>2</sub>, ... are independent iff only *one* of the linear combinations *a*<sub>1</sub>**v**<sub>1</sub>+*a*<sub>2</sub>**v**<sub>2</sub>+... gives a **0** result (namely that for coefficients *a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>, ... = 0).

```
|ssQ    % sum of absolute values of input plus 1
t_w     % duplicate, negate, swap
2$:     % binary range: [-S-1 -S ... S+1]
GZy1)   % push input. Number of rows (i.e. number of vectors), N
Z^      % Cartesian power. Gives (2S+3)×N-column array
!2$1!   % Permute dimensions to get N×1×(2S+3) array
G       % Push input: N×M array
*       % Product, element-wise with broadcast: N×M×(2S+3) array
Xs      % sum along first dimension (compute each linear combination): 1×M×(2S+3)
!       % Transpose: M×1×(2S+3)
Xa~     % Any along first dimension, negate: 1×1×(2S+3). True for 0-vector results
s       % Sum (number of 0-vector results)
2<      % True if less than 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 18 bytes

```
1<:[:-/ .*|:+/ .*]
```

This is a tacit verb that accepts a matrix with the vectors as columns and returns 0 or 1 depending on whether the vectors are linearly dependent or independent, respectively.

The approach is based on Anna's Matlab [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78095/20469) and Dennis' Julia [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78134/20469). For a matrix **X**, the square matrix **X**<sup>T</sup>**X** is singular (i.e. has zero determinant) if the columns of **X** are linearly independent. Since all elements of **X** are guaranteed to be integers, the smallest possible nonzero determinant is 1. Thus we compare 1 ≤ det|**X**<sup>T</sup>**X**| to get the result.

Examples (note that `|: >` is just for shaping the input):

```
  f =: 1<:[:-/ .*|:+/ .*]
  f |: > 0 1; 2 3
1
  f |: > 1 2; 2 4
0
  f |: > 2 6 8; 3 9 12
0
  f |: > 1 2; 2 3; 3 4
0
  f |: > 1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1
1
  f 0
0
  f (0 0 $ 0)
1
  f |: > 1 1; 0 1; 1 0
0
  f |: > 1 2 3; 1 3 5; 0 0 0
0
```

Made possible with help from Dennis!

Comment: I wonder if finding the inverse of the matrix is allowed. If it is, `1:@%. ::0:` for 10 bytes could be used. I think it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly, <s>5</s> 2 bytes

```
ÆḊ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4bhuIo&input=&args=W1sxLDAsMF0sWzAsMSwwXV0)

Comment: You don't need the `æ×Z` part. `ÆḊ` is implemented as `sqrt(det(A × A'))` for non-square matrices. I'm not sure if that would count as a LI built-in though...

Comment: Determinant is allowed.